# After Setting a value in cell function/sub then program exits - Macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

After searching more for this solution I asked in SO. I just trying to automate the work and new bie in VBA code. Here I m facing problem that when I update cell value in excel using macro. Then the program stops it not procceds to next step.

My sample code:

```
Private Function trim_Func(i As Integer, j As Integer) As String
    Dim fStr As String
    Set Workx = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, j)
    fStr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, j)
    fStr = trim(fStr)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, j) = fStr
    MsgBox Workx
    trim_Func = "Yes"
End Function
```

Here After this line "`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, j) = fStr` the function stopped not calling MsgBox or anyother. But the value is changed. I have another function after this to be called.

Edit: The Trim function is called like this after a button click in excel sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim data_value As String
data_value = trim_Func(2, 6)

// Some other conditions and functions
```

Edit :

I have provided sample tested screenshot. It does not return function or not going next to that value changed in cell.
Excel:
[image]

Code:
[image]

Comment: How is the function `trim_Func` called?  Can you please add this to your question ([edit]). Best is to provide a [mcve] so everyone can reproduce what you did.

Comment: Thanks, I have added when it is called in code. After a button click the function is called to trim the active cell.

Comment: You do not need a function for this. Change it to `Sub trim_Func(i As Integer, j As Integer)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The code is running fine here. It returns `yes` as expected. What is the exact value in `Cells(2, 6)`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout as long as he wants to return "yes" he needs a function (even if it doesn't make sense as it is now). Not clear what he is doing with this "yes" but at least it got asigned to a variable. Well, I would recommend to use a `Boolean` instead of a `String` if it is just a yes/no return.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Actually i have some trailing space in those cells example : 'Market Value  ' here the space. I did not get the MsgBox and return value from the above code

Comment: Thanks, @SiddharthRout I have just provided my code for sample. There ll be changes.

Comment: @UserLearning I tested your code and it runs fine. So either your example is not what you are actually doing or you forgot to explain some important details. If I put this code into a new blank workbook and add a worksheet "sales", it runs as expected.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ pls see . I have added screenshot from my code. I did not get function that return value and even cannot trigger MsgBox also.

Comment: Seems a very long way to `Trim` a cell. In `CommandButton1_Click`, you could just do: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(2,6) = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(2,6))`. If you have to use a UDF, rather than returning a string (`Yes`), I would just return a **`Boolean`**. Also, please use `Option Explicit`.. it's your friend

Comment: Does it work if you replace `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook`? And please also try to debug your code going throug it step-by-step using F8 and check your valriable values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I have found solution after much thinking. Made some mistake by asigning value in Set. Thats problem.

```
Function trim_Func(i As Integer, j As Integer) As String
        Dim fStr As String
        fStr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, j)
        fStr = trim(fStr)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Cells(i, j) = fStr
        trim_Func = "Yes"
End Function
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice to use `ActiveWorkbook` as at any given point, active workbook could not be the workbook you want to interact with. Qualifying the workbook would reduce unwanted issues

Comment: Thanks, So ThisWorkbook.Sheets is recommended ? I m newbie so thanks for suggestions. @Zac

Comment: @UserLearning `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook window that has the focus (is on top) which can easily change by a mouse click for example. While `ThisWorkbook` is always the workbook the current code is running in. So this is more reliable because it cannot be changed by user interaction.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: perfect explanation! :)